# Best way to call the function from one component to another component(not parent child)

Tags: angular, rxjs, components, behaviorsubject, angular14

What is the best way of calling function of one component from another component. When there is no connection between them. I tried by using behaviour subject but it is calling the function multiple times. Sometimes it is calling more than 5 times.

Comment: I'd recommend to move the function / method to a service and inject it to a component. Then you can independently call that function. Another option to export that function from anywhere. Then you can call it in any component.

Comment: See https://medium.com/geekculture/dependency-injection-in-javascript-2d2e4ad9df49

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do completely, but you could use [`share()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/share)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way to communicate between components in angular that don't have any child/parent relation ,is using a service.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what the components task is. So a simple, flexible way are `EventEmitter`

### Event Emitter

*ChildComponent*

```
outputData: EventEmitter<{anything: string}> = new EventEmitter();

...

onClickSomething() {
  this.outputData.emit({anything: "A text!"});
}
```

*Parent Component*

```
// html
<app-child (outputData)="myOuputData($event)"></app-child>

// ts
myOuputData(event: any) // or {anything: string}, or as interface and so on
  console.log(event.anything);
  // A Text!
}
```

### Input from Parent to Child

Then you can give the child some data from its parent:

*Child Component*

```
// ts
@Input() someText!: string;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes['someText'])
}
```

*Parent Component*

```
// html
<app-child [someText]="myVariable"></app-child>
```

So if the bounded **myVariable** changing the `onChange` event inside the child will fire and you can handle it.

### Service

For a cross communication a Subject in a Service is the best practice.

*myService*

```
private mySubject: Subject<string> = new Subject();

getMySubject() {
  return this.mySubject.asObservable();
}

doSomething(text: string) {
  this.mySubject.next(text);
}
```

*Component*

```
this.myService.getMySubject().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

> Please Note: on `ngOnInit` start subscription with a private variable inside the component and on `ngOnDestroy` **unsubscribe** it!! That can be a reason why it fires 5 times in your case.

To subscribe from one component **directly** to another is bad practice and don't will work the most of time!